# Error while installing PyTorch using pip - cannot build wheel

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, pytorch

I get the following output when I try to run `pip3 install pytorch` or `pip install pytorch`

```
Collecting pytorch
  Using cached pytorch-1.0.2.tar.gz (689 bytes)
Building wheels for collected packages: pytorch
  Building wheel for pytorch (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/chaitanya/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3v4wd97t/pytorch/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3v4wd97t/pytorch/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-8rsdyb8e
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-3v4wd97t/pytorch/
  Complete output (5 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-3v4wd97t/pytorch/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
      raise Exception(message)
  Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pytorch
  Running setup.py clean for pytorch
Failed to build pytorch
Installing collected packages: pytorch
    Running setup.py install for pytorch ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/chaitanya/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3v4wd97t/pytorch/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3v4wd97t/pytorch/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-eld9j0g4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/chaitanya/.local/include/python3.8/pytorch
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-3v4wd97t/pytorch/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-3v4wd97t/pytorch/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        raise Exception(message)
    Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/chaitanya/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3v4wd97t/pytorch/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3v4wd97t/pytorch/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-eld9j0g4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/chaitanya/.local/include/python3.8/pytorch Check the logs for full command output.
```

I downloaded the matching wheel from [here](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html), but am couldn't figure out what to do with it. My Python installation is using anaconda3, if that's needed. What should I do from here? Tips on how I could have resolved this on my own would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From your error:

> `Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"`

which tells you what you need to know, instead of

```
pip install pytorch
```

it should be

```
pip install torch
```

> I downloaded the matching wheel from here, but am couldn't figure out what to do with it

Installing `.whl` files is as easy as

```
pip install <path to .whl file>
```

> My Python installation is using anaconda3

That is very relevant. You should generally avoid as much as possible to use `pip` in your conda environment. Instead, you can find the correct `conda install` command for your setup(cuda version etc.) from [pytroch.org](https://pytorch.org/), e.g. for cuda 11 it would be

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.0 -c pytorch
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and get back here.

Comment: The installation using conda is resulting in a ```NotWritableError```, i.e. user does not have write permission on this path, and sudo can't be used with conda from what I gathered on one of the issues on their github. Is my only way out a complete reinstallation of Python3?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the anaconda folder, they are probably not set correctly

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Comment: Ah.. I have windows